# pixhawk 1 and PM07 incompatibility

Tags: compatibility

I bought myself a package that includes a pixhawk1 3DR px4 (this one) and the PM07 Power Management Board from holybro, but they are not compatible. And I found some adaptaters but I don't know which one I should take. here's the link: https://store.mrobotics.io/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=MRC0203
or
https://store.mrobotics.io/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=MRC0203

.[image: this is my pixhawk]